# how can I use xml_find_first in a pipe? (no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character")

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I try to scrape a decree for university research, this code used to work with an older version of `rvest`

```
library("rvest")

read_html("https://jurispub.admin.ch/publiws/pub/cache.jsf?displayName=D-6666/2017&decisionDate=2019-04-04&lang=de") %>% 
    xml_node("div.content") %>% 
    as.character()
```

However, now I get an error:

> no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of
>   class "character"

Is this because xml_node is deprecated? How can apply `xml_find_first` in this pipe to get the same result?

Comment: What are you trying to scrape ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: works for me running as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling all packages I do not get this error anymore:

> no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of
>   class "character

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this error without the "" error

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tidyverse)

read_html("https://jurispub.admin.ch/publiws/pub/cache.jsf?displayName=D-6666/2017&decisionDate=2019-04-04&lang=de") %>% 
  xml_node("div.content") %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  str_trunc(100)
#> [1] "<div class=\"content\">\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\">\n<table ..."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thank you for your help. I have the " " in my code, just forgot to type it here. I corrected this in my question

Comment: and btw, what do you call a mess? :D I am always open for a hint how to better scrape this content

Comment: Html mess the code is fine :) sorry for the confusion